# Is "to [verb] will [verb]" a complete statement?

Tags: grammar, sentence, is-it-a-sentence

Let's have, for example, the following phrase.

> To create fancy product will require more effort.

Is it a grammatically complete and correct sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, the structure is actually "To verb-phrase will verb", and yes, it's a perfectly valid structure, although it can sound a bit stilted.  In your particular example, you almost certainly need an "a" before "fancy product", though.

Also, it's probably more common (and definitely sounds less stilted) to use a gerund phrase rather than an infinitive-to phrase, thus:

> Creating a fancy product will require more effort.

Comment: He could alternatively make it plural: `Creating fancy products will require more effort`.

Answer (score -1):

It is a sentence because there are subject ("to create fancy product") and a predicate that refers to the subject ("will require"), and it ends with a period.